# pg_connect with PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW flag

Tags: php, postgresql

I inherited a web application written in PHP that uses PostgresSQL as a database server.
I have no experience whatsoever with PHP and PostgresSQL, I come from a Java / C# background.
I'm studying how it works and while I was profiling it I noticed that the old programmer, during every page request, instantiate a class named Database in which he opens a connection to the database using something like this:

```
$this->connection = pg_connect($qs, PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW)
```

the profiler tells me this is a very expensive call (the page loads in 2.7 seconds...) and I was wondering if and when the flag PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW is actually needed. Since the connection string is always the same I tried to use pg_pconnect instead (or even pg_connect without that flag) and the page loaded in just 741 milliseconds.
Everything seems to work just fine right now but I'm kind of worried this could break the application somewhere, and since I'm not experienced in PHP I would like to know if the practice of using that flags could have a sense in a certain scenario that I need to check. Obviously, there are no unit tests to rely on.
As a side note, do you know good resources about how this pg_(p)connect really works? The official documentation doesnt seem to be deep enough.

Thank you!

Comment: The performance boost seems to imply that pg_connect is getting called several times per page, otherwise there shouldn't be any difference. Do the profiler results indicate that there are several calls per page?

Comment: just checked and your assumption is right, pg_connect is called 12 times

Comment: that seems just crazy, shouldn't the connection be opened once and then passed around to whoever needs it?

Comment: yes, that would be much better. It looks like the original programmer did not understand the performance implications of opening multiple connections to a database and thought that "force new" sounded safe. At least that's more plausible than opening all these connections on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: pg_pconnect will maintain one connection for the lifetime of each Apache backend, so don't be surprised if you end up with lots of connections. If they all end up issuing a query at the same time that'll clog the database server up.

I've never heard of a connection to the database taking 2 seconds though. I can start psql, connect, issue a query and get a response in 0.2s and that's on my old netbook. Check your networking setup or some such - there's something odd going on here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll check it out. about pg_pconnect: I tried with just pg_connect too without the PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW having the same performance boost. It's still not clear to me the whole life cycle that goes on here, do you have any good reference about this topic? Thank you

Comment: If it makes a change with pg_connect too, that suggests it is connecting multiple times in the script. That seems unnecessary (unless you know otherwise) but would explain the delay. Perhaps add a counter or log calls to see how many there are.

Comment: Yeah, as I already wrote in a comment above, the profiler shows that that function is called 12 times. It seems totally unnecessary, because a good design should be able to open the connection once and then pass it around, or at least this is what I think..

Answer (score 0):

When used, this constant tells pg_connect to create a new connection every time instead of using already opened ones. This might indicate the programs uses some session dependant features like:

- postgres session variables ([search_path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) ?)
- temporary tables that should not exist when instantating connection
- (bad) manual use of [sequence functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html)

Good luck

Comment: It seems it doesn't use temporary tables at all, can you please elaborate more on the other two points? That would be very helpful! Thank you again